# Entire expansion of a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to solve this exercise

Let $I = \{ e^{iθ}: 0 \lt θ \lt1 \}$ and $f:I \cup D(0,1) \to \Bbb C$ holomorphic on $D(0,1)$ and continuous on $I \cup D(0,1)$ so that $f(ζ)=e^ζ$ for all $ζ \in I$.

Show that there is an entire expansion for $f$ and find it.

I'm trying to use the reflection principle but so far I haven't come up with anything.

Any help?

Comment: $f(z) = e^z$ would seem to fit the bill.

Comment: And use identity principle?

Comment: Sorry I restated it, because I'm trying to show that it can be expanded. I could use reflection principle so that $e^z - f(z)$ has a limit point inside the reflected domain but I'm stuck with the details

Comment: I'm sorry but it looks to me that in your definition, $U$ is the empty set since $I$ is an arc on the border of the open disk and therefore cannot be open. Even if you mean the arc $I$ itself, that's still not open and I don't see how I can use the identity principle.

Comment: right my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous and $\lvert f(z) \rvert > 1$ on $I$ there is an open neighborhood $U \supset I$ such that $f(z) \neq 0$ for all $z \in U' = U\cap(I\cup D(0,1))$. Then there is a function $g$, holomorphic on $U\cap D(0,1)$ and $g(z) = z$ on $I$ such that $f(z)=e^{g(z)}$ for all $ z\in U'$. By the reflection principle this $g$ extends holomorphically over $I$ and since $g(z) = z$ on $I$ it follows that $g(z) = z$ everywhere on $U'$. Therefore $f(z) = e^z$ on $U'$ so it extends to the entire function $e^z$.

Comment: I don't get what is your $U$, knowing that $I$ is just an arc of the unit circle

Comment: Thank you, I think I got it!